# How do you create your own quick commands in Vivaldi?

Tags: linux, windows, mac, browser, vivaldi

I am using the new Vivaldi browser. On the [Vivaldi](http://vivaldi.com) website, it says:

> Quick commands menu is highly customizable allowing you to create your own commands and run them instantly.

But, how do you create your own quick commands in Vivaldi?

Answer (score 4):

This may be a case of marketing people taking artistic liberties on the web page promoting Vivaldi.  "Creating your own commands" appears to be a bit of a misnomer.

I posed the question on the Vivaldi forum and the gist of the responses (from a moderator and a "platinum" member) is that this refers to several features of the Quick Commands menu.

- You can customize the menu by adding shortcuts for commands to the menu (creating new menu selections, or "commands").

  Creating shortcuts: http://vivalditips.com/customization/shortcuts

  The [main Vivaldi web page](https://vivaldi.com/) shows the shortcuts being included in the menu.  I didn't find documentation on explicitly adding them to the menu, so I'm just assuming that this is automatic.
- You can type a free-form "command", which initiates an indexed search as you type to bring up existing commands that might include what you want: http://vivalditips.com/efficiency/quick-commands

  Since what you type isn't an existing command and it leads to executing the action you want, you've "created your own command".